# How to do Gene Expression dataset analysis with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, bigdata

Our dataset consists of 50K+ gene expressions collected over 100's of samples. This csv file is of size 70MB only. Running on R local gives an error: "Cannot allocate vector of size 22gb" at line 6 below. This was the code written:

```
data=as.matrix(read.table("geneExp.csv.csv", row.names = 1, header =T, sep = ','))
logdata=log2(data)
t_logdata=t(logdata)
output=/* the output label vectors 0 or 1 */
library(MASS)
lda.fit=lda(output~., data=as.data.frame(t_logdata), CV=TRUE)
summary(lda.fit)
```

LDA was tried as its also a dimensionality reduction approach for purposes of experimentation only. Here is a snapshot of the data: [image] - rows are genes and columns are samples. 
We could not find a comprehensive online post that goes over writing R code (such as the one submitted using cloudml_train(file="train.R") )run this on the cloud. We have tried using cloudml from rstudio although, it exited with error. Perhaps this code is not suitable to run on cloudml ? Should this be changed to tensorflow code ? An example of running an LDA model on the cloud would help. Thanks.

Comment: "Cannot allocate vector of size" means the machine has insufficient RAM for what you want to do. Your dataset doesn't seem that big, but I'm not sure what resources are required by `lda`. Also your code is converting `data` from a data frame (the output of `read.table`) to a matrix, and then back to a data frame. This is wasteful and unnecessary.

Comment: googling "linear discriminant analysis R memory" brings up [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HiDimDA/). I don't know if it's useful or not, but SO is for questions about *specific* programming problems - not for requests for pointers to tutorial material ...

Comment: @BenBolker Sure, sorry about that.I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @neilfws thanks. yes, the dataset is a few MBs only.thanks for the code review comment.

Comment: that helps, but I'm afraid this question is still pretty vague/broad. If you've tried [Cloud ML](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) and had trouble, why not edit your question with specific details about that? [This paper](http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/pdf/tkde08_dcai1.pdf) has some information about the memory intensity of LDA.

Comment: and can we see something about your data? `str()` is not a particularly convenient format for wide data, but you could show us part of it ...

Comment: @BenBolker yes, i understand, thanks for the links.i have added a snapshot of the data.hope that's ok.

Comment: snapshot doesn't really help that much. Have you tried following my example below, but with your data?  I would suggest using the matrix and response directly as `x` and `grouping` rather than going through the data frame/formula route, that may take more memory ...

Comment: @BenBolker yes Sir, thank you. sorry for the delay.it takes much more than the 163s and Rstudio does not respond after a while.I will check out the book on Advanced R.Thank you.I also found this tool called h2o that gives access to a free cluster with 4 vnodes.Still trying to get a model run on it successfully although.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but a suggestion for exploration (and too long/formatted for a comment). I hacked together a function that runs LDA on a trivial, synthetic data set, just to get an idea of what can be done (I'm running this on a Linux VM machine with <5G of memory on an oldish MacBook Pro ...)

```
f <- function(nr=200,nc=1e3,seed=101) {
    set.seed(seed)
    grouping <- rbinom(nr,size=1,prob=0.2)
    x <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc),nrow=nr)
    m <- MASS::lda(x=x,grouping=grouping)
    return(m)
}

system.time(m0 <- f())     ## 1 second
system.time(m0 <- f(5e3))  ## 30 seconds
system.time(m0 <- f(8e3))  ## 48 seconds
system.time(m0 <- f(25e3)) ## 163 seconds
```

So I can easily get up to 200 rows x 25000 columns (and `top` is reporting only 25% memory usage for the biggest example, i.e. around 1G), although things are starting to get a little slower than I want.

Wickham's [Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#memory-profiling) has some stuff on memory profiling ...